# Line plot for over 1 million datapoint

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, line-plot

I am having hard time plotting a desired line plot. I have a dataset containing 23 columns 21 columns are %age amount paid from 0-2 with a stepsize of 0.1, 1 column for the user id for that particular customer and the last column in the customer segment that he belongs to. I want to plot for all the customers in my dataset the payment pattern with 0-2 with 0.1 stepsize on my x-axis and the values for %age paid on the y-axis and color each line of a customer based on the segment that he belongs to. My dataset looks like the following:

```
Id        paid_0.0 paid_0.1paid_0.2paid_0.3paid_0.4 Segment
AC005839    0.30    0.38    0.45    0.53    0.61    Best
AC005842    0.30    0.30    0.52    0.52    0.52    Best
AC005843    0.30    0.38    0.45    0.53    0.61    Best
AC005851    0.24    0.31    0.35    0.35    0.51    Medium
AC005852    0.30    0.38    0.45    0.53    0.61    Best
AC005853    0.30    0.38    0.45    0.53    0.61    Best
AC005856    0.30    0.38    0.45    0.53    0.61    Best
AC005858    0.30    0.38    0.45    0.53    0.54    Best
AC005859    0.33    0.43    0.54    0.65    0.65    Best
```

I am trying to generate a plot as below:
[image]